# CodePen console will not give any output

Tags: javascript, codepen

I am doing an exercise involving Objects, and to see the output I use the console on CodePen. I have written the following code, but the console is not giving any output, can someone help me indicating what is wrong with my code?

I need to print "In school, I'll learn ExpressJS and ReactJS." using template strings.

```js
{
  let basic = {
    language: "JavaScript",
    frameworks: [{
        end: "back",
        list: [{
            name: "ExpressJS",
            released: 2010
          },
          {
            name: "MeteorJS",
            released: 2012
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        end: "front",
        list: [{
            name: "ReactJS",
            released: 2013
          },
          {
            name: "VueJS",
            released: 2014
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

}

console.log(basic.frameworks[0].list[0].name); // => ExpressJS

console.log(`In school I will learn ${basic.frameworks[0].list[0].name} and ${(basic.frameworks[0].list[0].name}`); // => In school, I'll learn ExpressJS and ReactJS.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! There're few things you have to change

1. Convert your console.log to a string literal with backticks ``
2. Remove `(` from `${(basic.frameworks[0].list[0].name}`
3. Your basic variable definition shouldn't be under `{}`.

That should solve your trouble!

```js
let basic = {
  language: 'JavaScript',
  frameworks: [{
    end: 'back',
    list: [{
      name: 'ExpressJS',
      released: 2010
    }, {
      name: 'MeteorJS',
      released: 2012
    }]
  }, {
    end: 'front',
    list: [{
      name: 'ReactJS',
      released: 2013
    }, {
      name: 'VueJS',
      released: 2014
    }]
  }]
};

console.log(basic.frameworks[0].list[0].name); // => ExpressJS


console.log(`In school I will learn ${basic.frameworks[0].list[0].name} and ${basic.frameworks[0].list[0].name}`);
```

Comment: @GonçaloMalveiro You're welcome! Would you mind accepting the answer if this has solved your problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `basic` isn't defined (watch your browser console).

Remove the bracket `{` before and after your var definition